# PySpark DataFrame multiply columns based on values in other columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Pyspark newbie here. I have a dataframe, say,

```
+------------+-------+----+
|          id|  mode|count|
+------------+------+-----+
|     146360 |   DOS|   30|
|     423541 |   UNO|    3|
+------------+------+-----+
```

I want a dataframe with a new column `aggregate` with `count * 2` , when mode is `'DOS'` and `count * 1` when mode is `'UNO'`

```
+------------+-------+----+---------+
|          id|  mode|count|aggregate|
+------------+------+-----+---------+
|     146360 |   DOS|   30|       60|
|     423541 |   UNO|    3|        3|
+------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Appreciate your inputs and also some pointers to best practices :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**: using `pyspark.sql.functions` with `when` :

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col
df = df.withColumn('aggregate', when(col('mode')=='DOS', col('count')*2).when(col('mode')=='UNO', col('count')*1).otherwise('count'))
```

**Method 2**: using SQL CASE expression with `selectExpr`:

```py
df = df.selectExpr("*","CASE WHEN mode == 'DOS' THEN count*2 WHEN mode == 'UNO' THEN count*1 ELSE count END AS aggregate")
```

The result:

```
+------+----+-----+---------+
|    id|mode|count|aggregate|
+------+----+-----+---------+
|146360| DOS|   30|       60|
|423541| UNO|    3|        3|
+------+----+-----+---------+
```